# changing installed package default language/locale

Tags: python, django

i'm very new to python and django

i've installed package called django-registration using pip
it was installed in

```
C:\Python344\Lib\site-packages\registration
```

so i want to change the default language from english to my own language

so i've looked into `locale` directory in

```
C:\Python344\Lib\site-packages\registration\locale
```

and i saw it already has my language in there (fr) ... so i guess i dont have to translate it myself

so how can i change default language from `en` to `fr` ?

i guess it has a very simple answer , i've searched around a lot with no result (i have to say python/django is not very noob friendly specially for someone who is coming from php world )

i've tried the simplest possibly stupidest way ... coping `django.mo` and `django.po`  from `fr` folder to `en` folder to overwrite english files  but still it runs with english language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'
```

in your settings.py file